# UIView Inside UIScroll not following Frame rules

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

I have a weird problem. I am trying to have a UIScrollView at one particular section of the screen containing 3 UIViews along with UIPageControl. I am using storyboard. I have added a UIScroll view with dimensions (0,0,288,225) for an iPhone app.

I have added three UIViews with the following frame:

View1: (1,1,286,223),
View2: (289,1,286,223),
View3: (576,1,286,223)

In the code i have given Content size as [864,228]. Other attributes set for Scroll view:

1. Paging Enabled: True
2. Direction Locked Enabled: True
3. Show Horizontal Indicator: False
4. Show Vertical Indicator: False

The Problem I am facing is that when I run this app on the simulator or on a real device, when the view loads, the View1 is loaded with a vertical offset. 
When I do a horizontal scroll the View scrolls up properly and the View2 is rendered properly. I have given the Height of content view same as the height of scroll view, that ideally should disable Vertical Scrolling but it stills allow me to scroll vertically by that same amount the first View was offset on first load.

Please let me know if someone know why this is happening.

I am using XCode 5.0 (5A1413) on OS X Version 10.8.4

Comment: Which version if iOS are you targeting? Which method are you adding your views from?

Comment: iOS 7 and i have added the view using story board. I have given the content size in viewdidLoad method. The Parent UIView has two UIScrollViews. One below another. The below one renders properly. The issue only with the top one.